# System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

What does it mean when MS Visual Studio 2005 throws this message?

```
"The type initializer for 'RMDC.clsVariables' threw an exception."
```

**Error log is as follows**

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  Message="The type initializer for 'RMDC.clsVariables' threw an exception."
  Source="RMDC"
  TypeName="RMDC.clsVariables"
  StackTrace:
       at RMDC.clsFunctions.getRegistryValue() in D:\Magnus Project\Project Backup\RMDC\RMDC\Class\clsFunctions.cs:line 704
       at RMDC.Program.Main() in ..\RMDC\RMDC\Program.cs:line 39
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**The class with error in question**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;


namespace RMDC
{
    class clsVariables
    {
        public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

        public SqlDataAdapter sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        public DataSet sDataSet = new DataSet();

        public static string sMessageBox = "";
        public static string sUsername;
        public static string sUserFullname;
        public static string sUserLogin;
        public static string sUserType;
        public static int sUserID;
        public static string sServer = "system-10";
        public static string sDatabase = "";
        public static string sDBUserID = "";
        public static string sDBPassword = "";
        public static bool sDontShow = false;
        public static string sCompanyName;
        public static string sContactName;
        public static string sCompanyAddress;
        public static string sPhoneNumber;
        public static string sFaxNumber;
        public static string sEmailAddress;
        public static string sWebAddress;
        public static string sOfficeCd = "01";
        public static int sfiscalYrId = 1;
        public static string sfiscalYr;
        public static DateTime sFiscalStart = DateTime.Today;
        public static DateTime sFiscalEnd = DateTime.Today;
        public static int sRoleId;

        public static byte[] m_barrImg;

        public static SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();

        public OpenFileDialog openIMG = new OpenFileDialog();

        public static NepEngCalanderProvider.NepEngDateClass nepDate = new NepEngCalanderProvider.NepEngDateClass();
        public static NumberToWord.InWordsClass NumericWords = new NumberToWord.InWordsClass();


        public enum QueryType
        {
            Insert,
            Update,
            Delete
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The first two lines of the stack trace give you file and line numbers to investigate. Start there.

Comment: @Quick Joe Smith: Quite possibly not, actually. They may just be showing the method that was called which *caused* type initialization. The OP should look at the actual type initializers.

Comment: That may be the case, but where else would you suggest somebody _start_ looking before posting a question on SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it means what it said - something in the type initializer for `RMDC.clsVariables` (which is an unconventional name, btw) went bang.

This could be a static variable initializer:

```
static int foo = GetInitialValueForFoo();
```

or a static constructor:

```
static clsVariables
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Whatever it was, it failed, leaving your type unusable.

If you run the code in the debugger, it should break in as soon as the exception is thrown, making it easier to work out what's going on.

Comment: What do you think might be the problem?  At the time of the exception being thrown, all the variable is doing is to initialize it's value.  In the class clsVariables it is declared as static string with "system-10", and at the time of exception it is just initializing it to "".

Comment: @Rabin: Without seeing any code, it's impossible to say. Post the static initializers and static constructor, and that may give a hint. Note that it will be running *all* the static initializers, not just the one your method needs to use.

Comment: @Rabin: That's an awful lot of static variables, most of which look like they shouldn't be static in the first place. And one instance variable of `SqlConnection` *and* a static variable of the same type? Ick. I'd suggest refactoring to start with. My *guess* is that it's  NepEngCalanderProvider.NepEngDateClass or NumberToWord.InWordsClass that's causing the problem, but it's hard to say. Have you tried running in a debugger yet?

Comment: Yes.  I tried debugger.  I will try to delete and add those two dll's and see if I can get it running again.  About the statics, I have no idea who did all those. But yes there seem to be a lot of those there :)

Comment: @Rabin: And what happened when you tried in the debugger? Did it not break into the debugger when it hit the error? Note that the InnerException of the TypeInitializerException should say what actually went wrong.

Comment: @Jon :: It is fixed it.  You had already pointed me to the correct direction but did not realize it until I woke up this morning.  It was just case of using the wrong version of the dll file on my references.  Thanks friend.

Comment: @Rabin: Cool. Now go and refactor it to pieces :)

Comment: @Rabin I can't up-vote this enough. I had a TypeInitializationException as well, but it was coming from the the program `static Main()` function of a Service (which don't lend themselves easily to Debugging) and I couldn't properly attach a try/catch around `Main()` to get my logger to tell me the stack trace. However, Rabin, you idea of updating DLLs reminded me I had to do some updating myself. And that did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to look at the exception's InnerException to find the reason that the TypeInitializationException got raised.  It's impossible to guess what's wrong without that information.

What ever code generated the error log needs a bit of work so that it doesn't forget to display the inner exception as well.  That's automatic if you use the Exception.ToString() method.  Implement an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException if necessary, log the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().